# angular 2 performance improvement

Tags: angular

I am developing  angular 2 application.But my first page loading is taking too long in IE and comparatively better in Chrome.I don't know whether I need to load all the libraries or how can I predict those libraries which are essential and which are n't.Please let me know how can  I decrease initial load time in angular 2.

Comment: you can load Libraries from cdn...

Comment: My question is how shall I decrease innitial load time(time taken to load first page) ??

Answer (score 1):

you can use webpack module bundler to convert your app to small bundles
and then you can load every single bundle on demand.
and here is an example

https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/angular-2-lazy-loading-with-webpack-d25fe71c29c1#.18wg9kjuw

and this is webpack docs

https://webpack.github.io/